# Assign all elements inside object to empty string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an `errors` object:

```
data() {
    return {
        ...
        errors: {
            login: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            },
            register: {
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                password_confirmation: '',
            },
        }
    }
},
```

How can I set the value of all items inside `errors` object to `''` (just clear them)?
I can clear all items inside `data` object with
`Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));`
But
`Object.assign(this.$data.errors, this.$options.data.call(this));`
or
`Object.assign(this.$data.errors, {});`
or
`this.errors = ''`
or
`this.$set(this.$data.errors, '');`
doesn't work.

---

**Update 1**
This one works for clearing `errors.login`:
`Object.assign(this.$data.errors.login, this.$options.data.call(this));`
I think I cann pass a variable to `clear(obj)` and use it
`Object.assign(this.$data.errors.obj, this.$options.data.call(this));`
but anyway looking how to clear all `errors` object.

**Update 2**
`Object.assign(this.$data.errors.register, this.$options.data);`
clears only `email` and `password` inside `errors.register` - can't get that logic.

Comment: Do you want the login object to be set to the empty string (e.g, it wouldn't be an object any more, but an empty string), or the values with the login object to be set to the empty string? If the latter, it's simple recursion.

Comment: @DaveNewton values inside `login` and `register` objects to be set to the empty string

Comment: So simple recursion then. Some JS libs have convenience methods for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by iterating all keys of the object and recursive by object values.

```js
function empty(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k){
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            return empty(object[k]);
        }
        object[k] = '';
    });
}

var object = { errors: { login: { foo: 43, bar: 23 }, register: { baz: 'aaa', inner: { key: 'value' } } } };

empty(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Actually, I reading the question again, I'm not clear what the OP wants.

Comment: @Andy I've updated my question, I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

In fact no need to do some recursive stuff or whatever. Just:

- Declare `errors` at `null` in your data's component
- Declare a `resetErrors()` method who instanciate `this.errors` like you want, and call that function when your component is `created()`
- Call `this.resetErrors()` whenever you want to reset/clear your errors object.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      errors: null
    }
  },

  methods: {

    resetErrors() {
      this.errors = {
        login: {
          email: '',
          password: '',
        },
        register: {
          name: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          password_confirmation: '',
        }
      }
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.resetErrors();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="resetErrors">
    Clear errors
  </button>

  <pre>
    {{ errors }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`. I guess this errors isn't connected with your JSFiddle example...

Comment: Please place the answer here, rather than linking to it -- linkrot would make this answer useless to future users. (SO has the same functionality as jsfiddle; click the document-with-angle-bracket icon in the toolbar above the text field.)

Comment: @DanielBeck I've edited my answer - no more JsFiddle but SO code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = data();
 for(const key in result.errors)
   result.errors[key] = "";
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set "login" etc to the empty string, not the key values in the "login" object?